# Dissimilar Features between two documents

Tags: nlp, nltk, gensim, cosine-similarity

I am trying to find the dissimilarity between the two documents. I am using gensim and so far have obtained similarity score.

Is there any way to know the dissimilarity score and dissimilar features between two documents?
And how to evaluate it?

Comment: For a generic domain, don't you think (1 - cosine_similarity) could be the measure of dissimilarity?

Comment: Thanks. This is what i have evaluated so far. But i have not been able to find out dissimilar features.

Answer (score 0):

Cosine similarity using word vectors gives the semantic similarity between two sentences. First, let's understand how this is calculated. Suppose there are two vectors representing two text documents,

[image]

and

[image].

Then the dot product of the vectors is given by

[image].

Geometrically, theta represents the angle between the **a** and **b** vectors on a plane. So, smaller the angle, more is the similarity. Cosine similarity method thus reports this angle measure. Now geometrically, if the difference between the two vectors is less, then the angle is small, and thus cosine similarity is high. If the angles are far and near 90', then the cosine of that is near zero.

So, **low scores of cosine similarity represent unrelated vectors.** Of course, unrelated vector may be a measure of dissimilarity in case of text documents. Otherwise, if the **angle is close to 180' then cosine similarity will be close to 1, but will be negated.** This could mean that the two documents have the opposite meaning.  This is again a different type of dissimilarity.

To sum it up, you can use both unrelated and opposite vectors to measure dissimilarity depending upon your application.
You may also consider syntactic differences such as the difference in dependency parse trees, named entities, etc. But again without knowing what exactly you are trying to achieve, its difficult suggest a single method.